# dynamic file upload form fields, can they be saved before for submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, file-upload

I have a page where a user can select different sets of 'tiles'. Each tiles have their own set of form fields.

As each tile is selected, the form fields are dynamically generated and saved as a data attribute like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tile[]" value="{"ct_id":"115","tile_id":"3","position":"2","configuration":"{\"data\":{\"image\":\"https:\/\/fthmb.tqn.com\/BFOuJ7esfMbaiQ3pkixGKJpCCZI=\/1200x800\/filters:no_upscale():fill(transparent,1)\/stockinvesting-5824dac45f9b58d5b1b85692.png\",\"link\":\"http:\/\/www.cnn.com\"},\"title\":\"some test title\"}"}" data-tile-id="3" data-tile-position="2">
```

this allows user to select multiple tiles and have each their own.
[image]

here is the sample tile being added. as you can see there is a file upload input field.
[image]

Here is the problem, when a form field is a file upload form field... 
A user selects a file to upload... I do not want it to upload until the form is saved...

Is it possible to have the source file saved temporarily on the page? and don't actually upload / stream (storage planning to use is AWS S3) until the entire page form is submitted?

I have tried just save the form upload input value, it just gives me c:\fakepath{filename.png}... but it doesnt actually upload anything.

Any help / direction on this appreciated.

edit: the add tile button does the following: it takes on the input from the tile modal and appends the value selected in to the page form hidden input as a value. 
when the entire form is submitted, it does a post request for the hidden inout and parses the 'value' to save in to database.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button:contains("Add")', function(){
  $("#tile-add-modal").modal('show');
  $curPosition = $(this).data('position');
  $('#modal-save').off('click');
  $('#modal-save').on('click', function(){
    $curIndex = $('#tile-select .active').index('#tile-select .carousel-item');
    $curData = $('#tile-select .active').carousel($curIndex).data('value');
    $dataDisplay = JSON.parse($curData.display);
    $dataSettings = JSON.parse($curData.settings);
    $dataConfig = JSON.parse($('div.campaign-tiles [data-tile-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').val());

    $('div.campaign-tiles .btn-tile[data-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').text('Edit').attr('data-tile-id', $curData.tile_id).attr('data-target', '#tile-edit-modal');
    $('div.campaign-tiles [data-title-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').text($curData.name);
    $('div.campaign-tiles [data-color-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').removeClass($('div.campaign-tiles [data-color-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').data('color-value')).addClass($dataDisplay.color).data('color-value', $dataDisplay.color);
    $('div.campaign-tiles [data-icon-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').attr('class', 'far fa-' + $dataDisplay.icon);
    $('div.campaign-tiles [data-type-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').text($dataSettings.type);

    var frmData = {};
    frmData.data = {};
    $('#tile-select .carousel-item.active :input').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('name') == 'title') {
        frmData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
      }
      else {
        frmData['data'][$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
      }
    });

    $dataConfig.position = $curPosition;
    $dataConfig.tile_id = $curData.tile_id;
    $dataConfig.configuration = JSON.stringify(frmData);
    $('div.campaign-tiles [data-tile-position="' + $curPosition + '"]').attr('data-tile-id', $curData.tile_id).val(JSON.stringify($dataConfig));
    $('#tile-add-modal input[type="text"').val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: All those double quotes in that attribute... yikes.

Comment: they're all escaped, they're residual json object being parsed and passed to the input value. but yes, they could be prettier.

Comment: I think you'd need to show/explain how this is done now. Totally in js until the upload? Then I don't understand why the files would be uploaded before the form is "saved"/submitted.

Comment: sure. let me edit the question with the js that attaches to the form 'add tile' button. also the file upload isn't even initiating.